# Linking error stdc++

Tags: c++, linux, ffmpeg

Why am I having these linking errors?

Here is a short sample of link errors, there are hundreds similar:

> /tmp/main-NtNkRQ.o: In function `__cxx_global_var_init':
>   /home/go/NetBeansProjects/Arbete_216/Ajourwork/Components/TheRealDeal/GUI/../../../Components/TheRealDeal/GUI/main.cpp:(.text+0x10):
>   undefined reference to`std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
>   /home/go/NetBeansProjects/Arbete_216/Ajourwork/Components/TheRealDeal/GUI/../../../Components/TheRealDeal/GUI/main.cpp:(.text+0x17):
>   undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
>   /tmp/main-NtNkRQ.o: In function`main':
>   /home/go/NetBeansProjects/Arbete_216/Ajourwork/Components/TheRealDeal/GUI/../../../Components/TheRealDeal/GUI/main.cpp:123:
>   undefined reference to `__cxa_begin_catch'
>   /home/go/NetBeansProjects/Arbete_216/Ajourwork/Components/TheRealDeal/GUI/../../../Components/TheRealDeal/GUI/main.cpp:127:
>   undefined reference to`__cxa_end_catch'
>   /home/go/NetBeansProjects/Arbete_216/Ajourwork/Components/TheRealDeal/GUI/../../../Components/TheRealDeal/GUI/main.cpp:127:
>   undefined reference to `__cxa_end_catch'
>   /home/go/NetBeansProjects/Arbete_216/Ajourwork/Components/TheRealDeal/GUI/../../../Components/TheRealDeal/GUI/main.cpp:123:
>   undefined reference to`std::terminate()'
>   /tmp/main-NtNkRQ.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTI26go_s_module_init_exception[_ZTI26go_s_module_init_exception]+0x0):
>   undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info'
>   /tmp/main-NtNkRQ.o:(.data.DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0[DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0]+0x0):
>   undefined reference to`__gxx_personality_v0'
>   /home/go/NetBeansProjects/Arbete_216/Ajourwork/Components/TheRealDeal/GUI/linuxobj//GO_C_Align.o:
>   In function `GO_C_Align':
>   /home/go/NetBeansProjects/Arbete_216/Ajourwork/Utilities/Image/Align/GO_C_Align.cpp:35:
>   undefined reference to`std::terminate()'
>   /home/go/NetBeansProjects/Arbete_216/Ajourwork/Components/TheRealDeal/GUI/linuxobj//GO_C_Align.o:
>   In function `~GO_C_Align':
>   /home/go/NetBeansProjects/Arbete_216/Ajourwork/Utilities/Image/Align/GO_C_Align.cpp:44:
>   undefined reference to`std::terminate()'
>   /home/go/NetBeansProjects/Arbete_216/Ajourwork/Components/TheRealDeal/GUI/linuxobj//GO_C_Align.o:
>   In function `GO_C_Align::de_init()':
>   /home/go/NetBeansProjects/Arbete_216/Ajourwork/Utilities/Image/Align/GO_C_Align.cpp:187:
>   undefined reference to`operator delete'
>   /home/go/NetBeansProjects/Arbete_216/Ajourwork/Components/TheRealDeal/GUI/linuxobj//GO_C_Align.o:
>   In function `GO_C_Align::init(int, int, GO_C_BufferManager*)':
>   /home/go/NetBeansProjects/Arbete_216/Ajourwork/Utilities/Image/Align/GO_C_Align.cpp:121:
>   undefined reference to`operator new[](unsigned long)'

I am on Debian 7, using Clang compiler. The code is built using a makefile system, the following compiler flags is used

```
CXXFLAGS = -g -I /opt/intel/composer_xe_2015.1.133/ipp/include/ -Wno-deprecated -D_GNU_SOURCE  -D_REENTRANT -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -I/usr/include/postgresql/ -I/usr/local/Qt/5.2.1/gcc_64/include/QtX11Extras/ -I/usr/local/Qt/5.2.1/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets/ -I/usr/local/Qt/5.2.1/gcc_64/include/ -I/usr/local/Qt/5.2.1/gcc_64/include/QtGui/ -fPIC -fPIE -I/home/go/ffmpeg_build/include/ -I/usr/local/Qt/5.2.1/gcc_64/include/QtCore/  -fPIC -fPIE -I/home/go/ffmpeg_build/include/libavcodec -I/home/go/ffmpeg_build/include/libavformat/


 $(CXX) -o xxx_GUI $(MAIN_FILE) $(TARGETROOT)/*.o  $(TARGETROOT)/*.a $(DEFINE_FLAGS) $(INCLUDE_FLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -lpq -lippi -lipps -lippcore -lpthread -lgcrypt -lippvm -lippcv -lippcc -L/opt/intel/composer_xe_2015.1.133/ipp/lib/intel64 -L/usr/local/Qt/5.2.1/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets/ -L/usr/X11R6/lib/  -lXv -lX11 -lXext -ltar
```

If I add -lstdc++ to my compiler options, FFmpeg gives link errors instead. I have wrapped FFmpeg includes in extern "C" as I have seen elsewhere on this site. It doesn't help. But I don't think that is the problem here.

FFmpeg is compiled as dynamic libs from source. (I had the same behavior when I linked static libs.)

I have checked the FFmpeg libs with ldd and the dependencies is in place. I have checked for 32/64 mix-ups but it all seems to be 64 as it should be.

root@antec:/usr/local/lib# file libavcodec.so.57.27.101
libavcodec.so.57.27.101: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=0x6bf103d9a0531802fdcc608a8032a77d5b89b898, stripped
root@antec:/usr/local/lib# file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: symbolic link to `libc-2.13.so'
root@antec:/usr/local/lib# file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so 
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), BuildID[sha1]=0xb5053aa2420700afc9687ab357a8d5d89fcb1bd0, for GNU/Linux 2.6.26, stripped

The example contained in FFmpeg source compiled and linked fine.

Is there any other external part that could give these errors? C++11? Any indication could help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably using `clang` as the value of variable `CXX`. Instead you should use `clang++`, because the `clang` frontend does not implicitly link with the C++ standard libraries.

Comment: go@antec:~$ echo $CXX
clang++

Comment: Regardless of the environment variable you should verify that the actual command line used to compile is correct, because something else in the makefile might incorrectly set `CXX`. Actually I think you should state in the question the complete command line used for compilation instead of just makefile rules.

Comment: You are right. Seems like Netbeans set CXX to clang. Didn't help that clang++ was specified as C++ compiler in Project Properties->Tool Collections Manager.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should add the path of .so or .a to your project instead of just copying it into your project folders.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: maybe like this:LIBS += your_path/libsupc++.a